# Hide NULL Row Groups JasperReports

Tags: null, jasper-reports, crosstab

Is there a way to hide rowGroups with NULL values in Crosstab ?

Comment: it is unclear what you want to achieve. E.g.
If you want to hide the entire row: filter out null data in your query. 
If you want to hide the specific field: select blank when null in the text field properties.

Comment: I can't comment the null data. For example, I have a LEFT JOIN in my query that the lists values for every date in a specified date range, there will obviously be nulls for some dates without values.

Comment: as far as I am concerned this is currently not possible within crosstabs. see http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/4626, so unfortunately only choice would be data manipulation.

Comment: @Ravi I've tried to reply to the similar question at this post: [How to show column at Crosstab even the data is absent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35998020/876298)

Comment: Thanks Alex. I've already done what you've suggested i.e. tweaking the query to get all the non null values.