# crosstab in jasper displays only the first column from input json

Tags: json, jasper-reports, json-query

my json is as follows

```
  "values": [
   {
            "purchase": {
                "name":"bags"
                },
                  "weekSpend": [
                    { 
                        "weekStartDate": 20181105,
                        "spend":100

                    },
                    {
                        "weekStartDate": 20181112,
                        "spend":200

                    }
                ]
    },
     {
            "purchase": {
                "name":"shoes"
                },
                  "weekSpend": [
                    { 
                        "weekStartDate": 20181105,
                        "spend":100

                    },
                    {
                        "weekStartDate": 20181112,
                        "spend":200

                    }
                ]
    },
   ]
```

I want to displayed  the grid where rows are 
productname and (columns by weekstartdate)

I followed the technique provided in [How to show column at Crosstab even the data is absent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931937/how-to-show-column-at-crosstab-even-the-data-is-absent)

However the productname are listed in row but the column are showing only first column.

my data set is as follows

```
<queryString language="jsonql">
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="productName" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="product.name"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[product.name]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="weekStartDate" class="java.lang.String[]">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="weekSpend.weekStartDate"/>
</field>
<group name="activityDateGroup">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{weekStartDate}]]></groupExpression>
</group>
```

my crossdata datasource is as follows

```
        <crosstabDataset isDataPreSorted="true">
            <dataset>
                <datasetRun subDataset="crossTabDataSet" uuid="e7b27508-8a48-4785-a48e-c646249df9a9">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("..values(@size > 0).*")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
            </dataset>
        </crosstabDataset>
```

and bucketexpression is on weekstartdate.

With these using JsonQL still only the first column is displayed

How do i get list of column based on weekstardate from iterating from rootnode.

i am using jasper studio 6.5.

Thanks
Anjana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an invalid field mapping: `weekStartDate` to `java.lang.String[]`, that is not supported in JSONQL.

Instead you could have this subDataset expression:

```
<datasetRun subDataset="crossTabDataSet" uuid="e7b27508-8a48-4785-a48e-c646249df9a9">
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("..values(@size > 0)..weekSpend.*")]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

with these field mappings:

```
<field name="productName" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^{2}.purchase.name"/>
</field>
<field name="weekStartDate" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="weekStartDate"/>
</field>
```

Comment: Thanks Narcis, This worked and i am able to get the columns displays

Comment: however encountered another with nested subdataset in crosstab. posted details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264657/jasper-map-crosstab-crosstabheadercell-from-subdataset-different-from-crosstabda.