# How to to display list of values in rowgroup in a crosstab?

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I'm unable to display list of values in crosstab rowgroup

I have this sample json

```
{
    "header": {
        "columnName": [
            "Product Store1",
            "location"
        ],
        "values": [{
                "purchase": {
                    "name": "bags",
                    "location": "MainMarket ",
                    "markets":["1","2","3"]
                },
                "weekSpend": [{
                        "weekStartDate": 20181105,
                        "spend": 100

                    },
                    {
                        "weekStartDate": 20181112,
                        "spend": 200

                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "purchase": {
                    "name": "shoes",
                    "location": "MainMarket ",
                    "markets":["a","b","c"]
                },
                "weekSpend": [{
                        "weekStartDate": 20181105,
                        "spend": 100

                    },
                    {
                        "weekStartDate": 20181112,
                        "spend": 200

                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

i want to show the output of market as row group as list of values Following this post [jasper map crosstab crosstabHeaderCell from subdataset different from crosstabdataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264657/jasper-map-crosstab-crosstabheadercell-from-subdataset-different-from-crosstabda)

I created crosstab parameter

```
<crosstabParameter name="listDS" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("purchase.markets")]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
```

then referenced this list in row group like this

```
<jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                                    <datasetRun subDataset="listSubDataset" uuid="b7fb45d8-2511-483e-9967-dd7efd283a1b">
                                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{listDS}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                    </datasetRun>
                                    <jr:listContents height="85" width="70">
                                        <textField>
                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="672350d1-e69e-4ef3-a9da-c36d66646220"/>
                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{colName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                        </textField>
                                    </jr:listContents>
                                </jr:list>
```

but the generated report displays market array as null

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="XTabReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="33c43d53-f9b3-4cc9-92b2-bedd805d66a9">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="json_crosstab/DataAdapter.xml"/>
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="XTabDS" uuid="9911fa6c-61b7-4952-81bf-4666e3e17fcf">
        <field name="weekStartDate" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="weekStartDate"/>
        </field>
        <field name="spend" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="spend"/>
        </field>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^{2}.purchase.name"/>
        </field>
        <field name="location" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^{2}.purchase.location"/>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="listSubDataset" uuid="01e76955-f29e-4d52-991b-aa0149bfdb37">
        <field name="colName" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="[0]"/>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="58">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="140" y="10" width="280" height="30" uuid="c8e3d7ad-eeb0-4cd1-8bef-88874e6921d4"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[List inside Crosstab]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="70" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="560" height="70" uuid="79f2afae-ac8b-4442-ac8e-ae1b1f68109f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.crosstab.style.header" value="Crosstab_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.crosstab.style.group" value="Crosstab_CG"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.crosstab.style.total" value="Crosstab_CT"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.crosstab.style.detail" value="Crosstab_CD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <crosstabParameter name="listDS" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource">
                <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("purchase.markets")]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="XTabDS" uuid="73b2e155-5015-451a-8813-7e2ed2f731fb">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("..values..weekSpend.*")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                </crosstabDataset>
                <crosstabHeaderCell>
                    <cellContents>
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="180" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="412c6db7-0cfa-4025-80cd-8c450f9eab96">
                                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value=""/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Horizontal">
                                <datasetRun subDataset="listSubDataset" uuid="a911c80f-a0b3-4395-bbd7-2c52c67585d3">
                                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{listDS}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                </datasetRun>
                                <jr:listContents height="30" width="90">
                                    <textField>
                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="168fd030-81cf-4b80-9766-6f4637c779ec"/>
                                        <box>
                                            <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        </box>
                                        <textElement>
                                            <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{colName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:listContents>
                            </jr:list>
                        </componentElement>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabHeaderCell>
                <rowGroup name="name" width="90" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="e8aa37d7-0921-40a6-8aca-1cccae61d26d"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <rowGroup name="location" width="90" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{location}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="86107a55-79be-4170-a2ee-b2a0ae5315e2"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{location}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="weekStartDate" height="30" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.Integer">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{weekStartDate}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="c65fb64a-d89b-4cc3-be28-d76624cb3d93"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{weekStartDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="spend_MEASURE" class="java.lang.Integer">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{spend}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="90" height="20">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="efb4b6dd-d9d3-4520-a94e-c0010a572b29"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{spend_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="20" columnTotalGroup="weekStartDate">
                    <cellContents/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="90" height="0" rowTotalGroup="location">
                    <cellContents/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="0" rowTotalGroup="location" columnTotalGroup="weekStartDate">
                    <cellContents/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="90" height="20" rowTotalGroup="name">
                    <cellContents/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="20" rowTotalGroup="name" columnTotalGroup="weekStartDate">
                    <cellContents/>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

excepted output is

[image]

but actual output is

[image]

Comment: has anyone come across this scenario is it possible to have list within crosstab in jasper

Comment: I have done similar stuff but getting the datasource from external application (calling a java class), since it will take me sometime to setup your environment let me know if you are still interested in this or if you already found a solution.

Comment: Hi, i havn't yet found a solution happy to look at your approach and give it a try please let me know on same .

Comment: Hi has anyone come across this scenario can we reference a list datasource from crosstab

Comment: has anyone tried displaying list of values in crosstab rowgroup from json. Appreciate quick help on same.

Comment: Has anyone tried displaying list of values in crosstab columngroup/row group like above example. Please suggest it will be helpful we need it urgently.

Comment: have you found the solution?